# problem with hector_slam

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using hector_slam with laser data of kinect but when i move kinect to create map the map jumps, and does not create a compleate map.

tnx for your seggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136876/problem-with-hector_slam/) by [parhamso](https://answers.ros.org/users/12516/parhamso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As also answered [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33933/kinect-doing-hector-slam/) (you´ll also find some other Q/As  regarding this), the low FOV and high noise do not work very well with the current implementation of hector_mapping.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0